# What is causing "Error 2501 OuputTo Action Cancelled"?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

Background:

I've been working on a macro to post company reports to out SharePoint site. The code runs in an instance of Access 2016. It works if I change the filelocation to one of my local drive, but not the Sharepoint site. I've spent days researching the error, but none of the results apply, and none of the fixes work.

Code:

```
Function CopySJIToWeb()


Dim fileLocation As String, fileName As String
Dim counter As Integer, i As Integer, store As Integer
Dim nstores(4) As Integer

nstores(0) = 31
nstores(1) = 37
nstores(2) = 41
nstores(3) = 44
nstores(4) = 57

FileName = "12 Dec 2015 Sales Journal.pdf"
counter = 1
store = 1

Do While counter < 59
     FileLocation = "http://192.168.100.12/holiday store " & store & "/holiday " & store & " sales journals/"
     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Sales Journal", acFormatPDF, FileLocation & FileName, True, "", 0, acExportQualityPrint
     SendKeys counter
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"
     counter = counter + 1
          If counter > 2 Then
               store = store + 1
          End If
          If store > 30 Then
               For i = 0 To 4
                    If store = nstores(i) Then
                    store = store + 1
                    End If
               Next i
           End If    
Loop

End Function
```

Running this throws the error: "Runtime error 2501. The OutputTo action will be cancelled."

My office account has the necessary permissions and in my browser I'm logged in as said account, so I can't see permissions being the issue. The network location is correct, and I've tried using both the ip address and site's name in the file location. I've made sure there are no non existent spaces or other characters. I've also tried using %20 instead of spaces in the filename, in case those spaces were being stripped. Microsoft's documentation of the 2501 runtime error has been incredibly unhelpful.

So what causes this error? What specifically is happening underneath it all? And what are other ways to resolve it?

Comment: A few questions (though I won't be able to help with Sharepoint, sorry): 1) The error is thrown on the `DoCmd.OutputTo` line? 2) What is the purpose of the `SendKeys` commands? 3) Is the error also thrown if you remove everything after the `DoCmd.OutputTo` line?

Comment: The error is thrown on the DoCmd.OutputTo line, yes. SendKeys lets the macro send key inputs automatically. In this case, it will put the store number into the report's prompt, then hit Enter. And yes, the error is thrown regardless of what is after that line.